# Get array of Last Inserted Ids mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a query like
`Insert into tbl(str)values('a'),('b'),('c')`

if  i had a single insert then by using `mysqli_insert_id($con)`  i could get last id inserted but how get all ids inserted in this  multiple insert query?

Answer (score 2):

This behavior of `last_insert_id()` is [documented in the MySQL docs:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

> The currently executing statement does not affect the value of
>   LAST_INSERT_ID(). Suppose that you generate an AUTO_INCREMENT value
>   with one statement, and then refer to LAST_INSERT_ID() in a
>   multiple-row INSERT statement that inserts rows into a table with its
>   own AUTO_INCREMENT column. The value of LAST_INSERT_ID() will remain
>   stable in the second statement; its value for the second and later
>   rows is not affected by the earlier row insertions. (However, if you
>   mix references to `LAST_INSERT_ID()` and `LAST_INSERT_ID(expr)`, the
>   effect is undefined.)

IF you really need it you can test it using foreach with array_push

```
 <?php

$InsetQueryArray = array(
    "Insert into tbl(str) values('a')",
    "Insert into tbl(str) values ('b')",
    "Insert into tbl(str) values('c')"
);

$allLasIncrementIds = array();

foreach ($InsetQueryArray as $value) {

    //execute it mysql 
    //Then use array_push 

    array_push($allLastIncrementIds, mysqli_insert_id($con));

}

?>
```

Comment: But will that affect performace ? Making server too slow?

Comment: Is there any diff between your query and 
`foreach(){
   mysqli_query(insert into ...)
//3 times a,b and c
}`

Comment: sending thousand individual queries from php instead of 3 long insert into ... values (),(),... IS definitely MUCH slower.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just for a few rows, you could switch to sending individual inserts with last_insert_id(). Otherwise it will slow down your application notably. You could make a marker for those bulk inserts, which gets set to a number identifying this bulk insert at the bulk insert itself and you can fetch those ids later on:

```
insert into tbl (stuff, tmp_marker) values ("hi",1715),("ho",1715),("hu",1715);

select group_concat(id) from tbl where tmp_marker = 1715;

update tbl set tmp_marker=0 where tmp_marker=1715;
```

If those bulk inserts have a meaning, you could also make a table `import_tbl` with user and time and filename or whatever and keep the 1715 as reference to that import.

EDIT: After discussion, I would go to an import-table

```
CREATE TABLE import (id int(11) not null auto_increment primary key, user_id int(11), tmstmp timestamp);
```

When an import starts, insert that:

```
INSERT INTO import set user_id = $userId;
```

in php:

```
$importId = last_insert_id();

$stmt = "insert into tbl (str, import_id) values ('a',$import_id), ('b', $import_id),('c',$importId);
```

Then you can do whatever you want with the id of your recently imported rows.

I have not made research if a multi-row-insert is guaranteed to lead to a consecutive row of IDs, as in a combination of last_insert_id() and num_rows is presupposed. And if that stays so, even when MySQL increases parallelization. So I would see it as dangerous to depend on it.

Comment: I used last_insert_id() and row_count() and it worked . Is those medthods ok?

Comment: I think it to be a bit dirty to depend on a packed block of IDs, but as long as it works it is ok. If you think that an "import" (or wherever you get the data from) is an entity, use an import-table. I am not sure what happens when the insert statement gets breaked or stopped with your method.

Comment: If a user inserts rows and i count the ids using my method and suddenly another user at the same time inserts then will those ids inserted by both users be mixed? Or they are inserted one bulk after another?

Comment: Yeah, good question. I expect it to be one query after the next, but you should try that with a script. I have no idea if you insert 20 or 2000 rows on a query. I would prefer my way, since that is only little more effort and I can store the inserting user, the time and so on in the "import" table. But that does not mean that the slightly simpler alternative is wrong. How important is this id-list? Whats goes wrong if the system mixes something up?

Comment: Quite important!
System gets disturbed!
Any chances of getting mixed up?

Comment: In average i insert not more than 100-300 queries together depending on user!

Comment: For 200 queries the answer from @samitha will be much slower than your current solution, so just add an import_id field if possible. It should not be too much work, and it could be 0 on default not to disturb possible other inserts.